# SharePoint 2013: How can I replace a video in an asset library?

Tags: document-library, video, asset-library

I have a video whose URL has already been distributed, but an edited version of the video now needs to replace the existing one. Is there a way to replace a video in an asset library while maintaining the URL? This can be done in Vimeo, but I can't find a way to do it in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the video has the same filename, just upload it again to overwrite the existing version. The URL to the video will remain the same in that case.

Comment: I've tried this, and it failed. The library just uploads the new video alongside the old one. I also tried uploading a video with an identical Name value. In that case, SharePoint adds an underscore and a six-character string of upper case characters to the end of the Name field. But it leave the original video in the library.

Comment: This is giving me no problems in site assets or in an assets library. When I drag it in, it sees the same file name an asks me if I want to overwrite. When I use the upload option, I have the overwrite box ticked and it replaces the video.

Comment: I admit, it is strange behavior. I would expect the library to simply prompt me to overwrite or to create a new version based on the file. I'm not sure why it is behaving so strangely. I'll keep digging and report back if I find out more.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. What worked for me was opening the video library in Explorer, then navigating into the folder with the video's title to find the actual MP4, making sure the filename of the new version was identical, then copying the video in through Explorer.

After some thinking, I got a prompt to Copy and Replace, Copy but don't replace, or Don't Copy, as one would expect with a file transfer. My Explorer window kept freezing up, though I don't know if that's related or if SP was just being weird today.

It did take FOREVER to upload, and seemed to get hung up around 95%, but it did eventually work. I went back to the library and can play the new version of the video and there were no issues. Checked the documents that linked to the video and the link remained the same.